# Invoke Web Service using c# Output in List Box Windows Form

Tags: c#, web-services, listbox

I feel like an idiot for having to ask this, but I'm struggling to output the numbers from the web service call to my list box. it just comes back with "Task2.wsCall.Service1SoapClient" written inside my list box. Where as I would expect something along the lines of 1, 2, 3 etc. the web service only has this inside it:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public int getNumber(int n)
    {
        return n * n * 100;
    }
}
```

So, I could be doing this completely wrong. Thanks to anyone who helps out, here's my code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnPress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
            {
             wsCall.Service1SoapClient CallWebService = new wsCall.Service1SoapClient();
             lstBox.Items.Add(CallWebService);

                //lstBox.Items.Add(i);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception caught.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you have not called the method.Try this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
      {
        wsCall.Service1SoapClient CallWebService = new wsCall.Service1SoapClient();

        lstBox.Items.Add(CallWebService.getNumber(i));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed code like this

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnPress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
                {
                 wsCall.Service1SoapClient CallWebService = new wsCall.Service1SoapClient();
                 lstBox.Items.Add(CallWebService.getNumber(i).toString());


// Changed Code Like this


                    //lstBox.Items.Add(i);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception caught.");
            }
        }
    }
```